# How to make ConEmu release prompt instead of closing tab, in case of cmd error?

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, tabs, conemu

I am opening a set of tabs in `Conemu`, using the following `start_all.bat` file:

```
"C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe" /cmd @C:\Users\Me\Desktop\start_scripts\aeg_tabs.txt
```

`aeg_tabs.txt` file looks like this:

```
C:\00aeg\02start_high.bat
C:\00aeg\03start_low.bat
C:\00aeg\04start_mid.bat
```

Is there a way to prevent `ConEmu` from closing the tab, in case of an error? For example, I would like to see and fix the error in the code, **and just be able to rerun the command from the same tab**, instead of opening manually a new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may turn on ‘Press Enter or Esc to close console’ confirmation for each tab
Just change your `aeg_tabs.txt`

```
C:\00aeg\02start_high.bat -new_console:c
C:\00aeg\03start_low.bat -new_console:c
C:\00aeg\04start_mid.bat -new_console:c
```

Comment: Yes, I will do that, but is there also a way to retrieve the cmd prompt, if the command fails/exits for some reason? I want to be able to restart it manually, within the same tab, without opening a new tab.

Comment: use `cmd /k C:\00aeg\02start_high.bat -new_console:c`

Comment: I tried it, but it still does not release the prompt to the user.

Comment: I don't understand. Show screenshots?

Comment: I apologize, I made a stupid mistake, I forgot the `cmd /k`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use DefaultTerminal feature. First go to ConEmu settings > Integration > Default terminal then click Force ConEmu as default terminal for applications. Then in Confirm Clsoe section, enable Always. Hope that helps